# Style all elements before :checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating my own star-rating system for my website. The user can select anywhere between 1-5 stars.

The idea is that the user has to click on a star to select a rating, and all stars left on the one clicked get highlighted, including the star clicked.

Behind the scenes, I have a radio button for each star. The radio button gets selected when a user clicks on a star.

However, I want to have the stars highlight on `mouseenter` and if the user doesn't click, on `mouseout` the stars should reset to the default value represented by the radio button.

[**Fiddly fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pz2dey7u/1/)

I'm not sure of how to best achieve this, and my current code does also give a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. No idea why. I can't find any infinite loops.

**HTML**

```
<div class="starrating-container">
   <div class="star"><input type="radio" name="star-radio" value="1" hidden></div>
   <div class="star"><input type="radio" name="star-radio" value="2" hidden></div>
   <div class="star"><input type="radio" name="star-radio" value="3" hidden></div>
   <div class="star"><input type="radio" name="star-radio" value="4" hidden></div>
   <div class="star"><input type="radio" name="star-radio" value="5" hidden></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.starrating-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.star {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url('http://www.timelinecoverbanner.com/cliparts/wp-content/digital-scrapbooking/lemon-star-md1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0);
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.star').on({
   'mouseenter': function() {
       $(this).nextAll().andSelf().css('-webkit-filter', 'saturate(1)');
       $(this).prevAll().css('-webkit-filter', 'saturate(0)');
   },
   'mouseleave': function() {
       $(this).siblings().find(':radio').each(function() {
         if($(this).val() > $('.star input[name=radioName]:checked').val()) {
            $(this).nextAll().andSelf().css('-webkit-filter', 'saturate(1)');
            $(this).prevAll().css('-webkit-filter', 'saturate(0)');
        }
      });
   },
   'click': function() {
      $(this).children(':radio').click();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's great solution: 
[Accessible star rating widget with pure CSS](http://lea.verou.me/2011/08/accessible-star-rating-widget-with-pure-css/)

Answer (score 1):

you have to stop the radio button from triggering the click on the parent element too:

http://jsfiddle.net/pz2dey7u/4/
(added some background color to see the effect)

```
$(this).children('radio').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: That stops the error, but now the checkboxes don't get clicked. Any idea why?

Comment: you could use: $(this).prop('checked', true); to check it. See edited answer